# How to keep links when moving work items (task, bug) between projects in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, integration, tfs-workitem

Our situation:
In TFS 2010 + VS 2010 environment, we need to move source code and work items from old project to new project (new project is just for renaming and restructuring purposes, they all under one project collection).

We used TF.exe command line utility moved source code, it's good and carried history and links (changeset links to original bugs/tasks). We are happy about it.

Trouble appears when We tried to use **TFS integration tool** (MS recommendation) to move work items, it only carries forward attachments but no links. We need those links to link to our changeset. it's very important to us.

As I dig deeper, I know this "move" is not "real move" but creating new ID and copy the old information. Just wonder is there a way to do the move and still keep our links in bugs and tasks.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I got the following link from [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217070832/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/how-to-move-work-items-between-team-projects.aspx).

Have you looked at [Hemi - Hemi is a tool that helps you move work items from one team project to another in Team Foundation Server.](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=hemi)?

I think this is TF2008 - so you may be able to update the source to VS2010

Comment: Actually, I already read those two entries. Hemi is a dead project in codeplex. The blog entry recommend old tools which are replaced by TFS integration tool. As I tested, the TFS integration tool is still very rough to use. It didn't move work items and keep links.

Comment: I don't understand why it's so hard to move work item under the same project collection. workItemId is unique, why MS decide to create a new one instead of just change the reference.